# Zend WHERE IN Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, zend-framework, multidimensional-array, pdo

I'm trying to perform the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM x WHERE (x.a, x.b) IN ((1, 'name'), (2, 'name'), (3, 'name'))
```

I tried to do it like this, but it doesn't work with multidimensional arrays. I also tried turning the array into a string but Zend won't swallow it.

```
$data = array((1, 'name'), (2, 'name'), (3, 'name'));
$select->where('(user_id, user_name) IN (?)', $data);
```

Comment: In the where clause, personally, I would try to call a **function** that creates the request dynamically `(user_id = val11 and user_name = val12) or (user_id = val21  and user_name = Val22) or ...`
Be careful with quotes. :) good luck :)

Comment: That is a good suggestion, but looking at the size of my actual array, I'd dynamically have to create a very large query (which I'd have anyway) with about 1500 OR statements. Is that ok?

Comment: This is a very good question.
There would have had the same problems if the where clause worked. Zend written Requette dynamically as suggested function. 
I think you should have to try. 
If it does not work, I can suggest you to fetch it all and filter PHP side.

Keep us informed.

Comment: I actually found an API that made what I tried to here obsolete. I might still try this for the sake of science tho. I'll be back soon!